# Error: Expected '{' before this. @override

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting an error that i'm not understanding in my flutter code.

this is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class ReusableScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  final List <String> dirs=['11', '12', '13', '14', '21', '22', '23', '24', '31', '32', '33', '34', '41', '42', '43', '44'];
  final String jour;
  final String heure;

  ReusableScreen({
    @required this.jour,
    @required this.heure,
})

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [for (var temp in dirs) AssetImage('assets/'+this.jour+"/"+this.heure+"/"+this.dirs[temp])],
    );
  }

}
```

this is the full error message :

```
lib/wid.dart:14:3: Error: Expected '{' before this.
  @override
  ^
lib/wid.dart:18:101: Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
      children: [for (var temp in dirs) AssetImage('assets/'+this.jour+"/"+this.heure+"/"+this.dirs[temp])],
                                                                                                    ^
lib/wid.dart:18:41: Error: A value of type 'AssetImage' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.
 - 'AssetImage' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_resolution.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_resolution.dart').
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
      children: [for (var temp in dirs) AssetImage('assets/'+this.jour+"/"+this.heure+"/"+this.dirs[temp])],
```

Can you help me figure out the problem ?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of the ReusableScreen constructor.

Answer (score 6):

you're missing a semicolon after the constructor

```
ReusableScreen({
    @required this.jour,
    @required this.heure,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the error

```
lib/wid.dart:18:101: Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
      children: [for (var temp in dirs) AssetImage('assets/'+this.jour+"/"+this.heure+"/"+this.dirs[temp])],
```

You have an error in this line :

```
AssetImage('assets/'+this.jour+"/"+this.heure+"/"+this.dirs[temp])
```

**Error: this.dirs[temp]**

You can't access to the `List<String>` data giving it a String. You need to give it a Integer like an array. Like `this.dirs[4]`

But because you're doing `(var temp in dirs)` you can simply give the `temp` value. (Because is the same result than `this.dirs[index]`)

**So it should be like this:**

```
AssetImage('assets/'+this.jour+"/"+this.heure+"/"+temp);
```

---

For the error

```
Error: A value of type 'AssetImage' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.
 - 'AssetImage' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_resolution.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_resolution.dart').
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
      children: [for (var temp in dirs) AssetImage('assets/'+this.jour+"/"+this.heure+"/"+this.dirs[temp])],
```

I think you need to wrap the AssetImage in a container